# Build iOS .framework where has PLCrashReporter dependent project for all architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, plcrashreporter, arm64

I have created a static library and added into the project another xcodeproj (PLCrashReporter)  file as a link, included the User Search Header Path to find the headers and then followed this framework [script](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework/issues/61) generating the .framework.

But when I get the generated .framework file and add it to a sample test client project I get 'Undefined symbols for architecture arm64'.

And the error is for my own project files not in the dependent PLCrashReporter files. Though other times I get no rule to process file "PLCrasgReporter files" for architecture XXX.

In the step where you define which headers are going to be public in your framework there are no headers for the PLCrashReporter since I have added it as a link to my project and added a target dependency to the static library target and link binary with project to the PLCrashReporter.

What would be the proper way to build a framework for all architectures with a dependent project files?

I use latest PLCrashReporter 1.2 rc2.
I have set build active architectures only to NO to all targets.
Added -all_load other linker flags to my static library.
All the instructions to the framework script found in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

The PLCrashReporter-iOS target already has support for generating the iOS/Simulator static .framework.

I haven't tried using PLCrashReporter as a subproject (it's intended to be used as binary), but in theory if you depend on the 'CrashReporter-iOS' target, you'll get a framework you can link against.

I'd also recommend the [PLCrashReporter mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/plcrashreporter) for project-specific questions; there's more latitude to discuss specifics in a threaded e-mail format.

Comment: Indeed it is more proper to get into a mailing list. My intent is to use the PLCrashReporter embedded to my .framework in the end, so it will be needed to link and included in the result .framework of mine.

Comment: For iOS you can also check out how HockeySDK does integrates PLCrashReporter into its framework: http://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS

Comment: I see that the have the .framework into their source. But you can't have a .framework embed into a .framework in iOS.